# Pygame in Python not responding?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to Python and I entered in the code from the book I purchased to learn about it. I am trying to make the basic Skiers pygame, and every time I run the module, the pygame window pops up black then says "not responding"
I'm using Windows 8, Python 2.5.7 and here is the code. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import pygame, sys, random

skier_images = ["skier_down.png", "skier_right1.png", "skier_right2.png", "skier_left2.png", "skier_left1.png"]

class SkierClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("skier_down.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [320, 100]
        self.angle = 0

    def turn(self, direction):
        self.angle = self.angle + direction
        if self.angle < -2:  self.angle = -2
        if self.angle >  2:  self.angle =  2
        center = self.rect.center
        self.image = pygame.image.load(skier_images[self.angle])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        speed = [self.angle, 6 - abs(self.angle) * 2]
        return speed

    def move(self, speed):
        self.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx + speed[0]
        if self.rect.centerx < 20:  self.rect.centerx = 20
        if self.rect.centerx > 620: self.rect.centerx = 620

class ObstacleClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, type):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite__init__(self)
        self.image_file = image_file
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = location
        self.type = type
        self.passed = False
    def update(self):
        global speed
        self.rect.centery -= speed[1]
        if self.rect.centery < -32:
            self.kill()

def create_map():
    global obstacles
    locations = []
    for i in range(10):
        row = random.randint(0, 9)
        col = random.randint(0, 9)
        location  = [col * 64 + 20, row * 64 + 20 + 640]
        if not (location in locations):
            locations.append(location)
            type = random.choice(["tree", "flag"])
            if type == "tree": img = "skier_tree.png"
            elif type == "flag": img = "skier_flag.png"
            obstacle = ObstacleClass(img, location, type)
            obstacles.add(obstacle)

def animate():
    screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
    obstacles.draw(screen)
    screen.blit(skier.image, skier.rect)
    screen.blit(score_text, [10, 10])
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 640])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
skier = SkierClass()
speed = [0, 6]
obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group()
map_position = 0
points = 0
create_map()
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                speed = skier.turn(-1)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                speed = skier.turn(1)
    skier.move(speed)

    map_position += speed[1]

    if map_position >=640:
        create_map()
        map_position = 0

    hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(skier, obstacles, False)
    if hit:
        if hit[0].type == "tree" and not hit[0].passed:
            points = points - 100
            skier.image = pygame.image.load("skier_crash.png")
            animate()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
            skier.image = pygame.image.load("skier_down.png")
            skier.angle = 0
            speed = [0, 6]
            hit[0].passed = True
        elif hit[0].type == "flag" and not hit[0].passed:
            points += 10
            hit[0].kill()

    obstacles.update()
    score_text = font.render("Score: " +str(points), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    animate()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Not necessarily a solution, but try upgrading to Python 2.7.

Comment: I would, but the book told me to only use their version :(

Comment: actually not everything changes between versions of python so there are small thingies like in pyton 2.7 you print like this: `print "something"` in 3.4.3 it is like that: `print("something")` you can easily find out these things and repair them so you can use book for 2.5.7 and write code in python 3.4.3 (you can look at online python library dor 2.5.7 and 3.4.3 and see how print and everything else work differently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the code, ran it, added random image so it don't throw error and the problem seems to be here:
`pygame.sprite.Sprite__init__(self)` line 31
you missed dot between `Sprite` and `__init__`
so the line should look like:

```
pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) #added dot
```

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you! :)